# Is it possible to inject a raw reference to a bean instead of AOP-proxy?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Does spring allow us to do so? I was reading the documentation and found **[that](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle-default-init-destroy-methods)**:

> Thus the initialization callback is called on the raw bean reference,
>   which means that AOP interceptors and so forth are not yet applied to
>   the bean.

So, I presume, spring creates aop proxy and inject it into a collaborating bean every time the dependency is needed. How can I avoid injecting such a proxy and provide a raw reference to a bean. In my particular case I'm injecting prototype-scoped beans into each other.

I think, avoiding  injectink the proxy may improve the performance...

Comment: It will and you will loose everything... No scoping, no transaction nothing. All that is implemented by proxies. Also the overhead isn't that big a few ms. so if you are worried about that I would suggest you first tune your database and transactions those are probably bigger wins then this minor gain (and with which you will loose everything).

Comment: @M.Deinum I presumed, but didn;t know for sure that the transactions are implemented via the proxies. Ok, won't ever think about that again.

Comment: Well actually it isn't so much proxies but AOP and by default proxies are used for AOP. You could use load or compile time weaving to apply AOP as well but that is tricker to setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum So, spring can also use load/compile-time weaving for AOP, can't it? I thought it's used in AscpetJ only, but spring in turn uses proxy-based AOP implementation. So, we can integrate it with each other and instruct spring use weaving-aop-implementation, is that right?

Comment: @M.Deinum I mean, for the often used  `@Trasactional` spring annotation we could use weaving-based AOP instead of spring's proxy-based one. Is that possible?

Comment: If you use compile time weaving you have to do nothing as it will be part of your byte code. For load time weaving you have to do some additional configuration (this is explained in the reference guide).